# Bathroom faucet stem stops loosening; can't get out

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I am trying to remove the stem below to fix a dripping faucet.  I use a wrench to loosen around the hex with the arrow.  With some force the stem begins to loosen (the threaded-looking part below loosens as well).  At some point however, I cannot loosen any further, nor can I pull the stem out vertically.

I am not sure of the brand of the faucet, but it's also pictured.  Any ideas?  Is this stem supposed to NOT come out?  Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the close-up in photo *1 just above the first set of threads there is a "c" shaped clip. With a small screwdriver (or nail) pry it off. Be prepared for it to shoot away.

Once removed the stem should slide (or un-thread) away from the base.